# How to make sharp triangle hole using subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: subdivision-surface

I wand to make a sharp triangle hole using subdivision surface.
[image: 1]

I tried to add different position or combination of edge cuts inside this "hole" like this:
[image: 2]

But this created strange looking things like:
[image: 3]

I know that is something with triangle-shape polygons but I have no idea how to get rid of them.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: You need supporting geometry not only inside cutout but also outside. Moreover this cutout is surrounded by ngons, which do not work well with subsurf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be a good start :

[image]

Another thing would be to do as much as you can from a bevel modifier with angle detection, weights and/or vertex groups. It has the advantage of being non-destructive and faster.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!